# Ubuntu Virtual Machine not detecting Arduino, it yields "Can't attach the USB"

Tags: ubuntu, usb, virtual-machine, port, arduino

I am facing an issue when I try to detect the Arduino on the Virtual Machine which is running Ubuntu 20.04. When I connect Arduino on my Laptop (Macbook), the Arduino IDE on the Mac detects the Arduino connection but when I turn on the Virtual Machine, it doesn't detect the Arduino.

Just to make sure that this error arises only with Arduino, I also tried connecting another device like Lidar which was being detected on the virtual machine. It is only the issue with Arduino that it is not being detected on the Virtual Machine.

I also made a few changes like in the **PORTS** settings of the Virtual machine. I changed the **Port Mode** from **Disconnected** to **Host Device** and provided the address like: **/dev/tty.usbmodem******** but it still is not being detected on the Virtual Machine.

Can you please assist with the appropriate course of action in this case?